# Keep getting undefined method 'title' while I don't have any method called title

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm basically trying to replicate the example provided here(http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) with slight change on names. Each `post` could have multiple `comment` but I'm having some trouble when submitting the comments.
[Error page when trying to create a post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2STla.png)

The closest thing I could think of is I have validations for the `post` objects to require the `title` field to be present. 
I've seen resolution for the similar issue is to make sure the right private/public scope is set for method within the controller but that doesn't seem like the case.

Here's my code for Comment Controller

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
end

private
    def comment_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:commenter, :body)
    end
end
```

Comment: Post your models as well.  They should have the relationships listed or else your @post.comments statement will error out.  Also, show us your form so we know if the post_id is actually being sent.

Answer (score 0):

Ahhhh I just realized my issue.
Turned out I put the `validates` within the ApplicationRecord and then having the `comment.rb` inherits the ApplicationRecord. By refactoring the validation to `post.rb` solves the problem.